# How do I start up a timer in reaction to a non-UI event (such as serial port activity)?

Tags: c#, timer, event-handling, serial-port

The timer (`System.Windows.Forms`) does start up properly when started from the main UI (via e.g. a button). But, I can't quite get it to start when the signal comes from another place—in this case, an event from a serial port.

I'm aware that somehow `BeginInvoke`/`Invoke` and delegates are needed here, but, as a new programmer, I don't get it and I need some help.

```
//button in the main UI. Fires up the timer.
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     timer1.Enabled = true; //this one here works perfectly
}

//an event handler for a serial port event, does NOT fire up the timer.
public void SomethingHappenedWithTheSerialPort(object sender, EventArgs eventrgs)
{
     timer1.Enabled = true; //does NOT work at all. I don't know how to use Invoke.
}
```

EDIT: This is how I open up the port and listen for PinChanged events.

```
int baudrate = 9600;
int databits = 8;

Main mainhandler = new Main();

System.IO.Ports.SerialPort ComPorttoUse = new SerialPort(Properties.Settings.Default.COMPortToUse, baudrate, Parity.None, databits, StopBits.One);
ComPorttoUse.Handshake = Handshake.None;

ComPorttoUse.PinChanged += new SerialPinChangedEventHandler(mainhandler.PortDetectWhatPinChanged);

ComPorttoUse.Open();
```

Comment: Have you checked if the event registered properly and you get into your code in "SomethingHappenedWithTheSerialPort" ?

Comment: Yes. I actually put a `MessageBox` together with timer1.Enable. The MessageBox DOES show up but the timer still doesn.t start.

Comment: Could you please post the code that shows how you are setting up the serial port and how you are subscribing `SomethingHappenedWithTheSerialPort` to a serial port event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> //an event handler for a serial port event, does NOT fire up the timer.
> public void SomethingHappenedWithTheSerialPort(object sender, EventArgs eventrgs)
> {
>      timer1.Enabled = true; //does NOT work at all. I don't know how to use Invoke.
> }
> ```

This event handler is never invoked because it appears that you have not subscribed it to any event of your `SerialPort` object. Instead, you have subscribed a handler method called `PortDetectWhatPinChanged` to the `PinChanged` event:

> ```
> ComPorttoUse.PinChanged += new SerialPinChangedEventHandler(mainhandler.PortDetectWhatPinChanged);
> ```

If you expect `SomethingHappenedWithTheSerialPort` to be invoked, you need to "add" it to the event:

```
ComPorttoUse.PinChanged += new SerialPinChangedEventHandler(SomethingHappenedWithTheSerialPort);
//                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                  ^
//                         note: not required, the compiler can usually infer this bit.
```

And your handler method must have a signature compatible with that of the `PinChanged` event, so you need to change it to:

```
public void SomethingHappenedWithTheSerialPort(object sender, SerialPinChangedEventArgs e)
{                                                          // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    timer1.Enabled = true;                                 //    this needs changing!
}
```

Comment: Still nope.  I the timer not being started from the UI thread is the main problem. That's why invoke stuff needs to be involved here.

Comment: Someone reputable said this: `You cannot reliably enable the timer from a worker thread. Like the one that's used to call the SerialPort.DataReceived event. You must use this.BeginInvoke() to ensure that you run the code on your UI thread. Btw, write code like a potential employer is going to read it some day. Or an SO user.`. How do I go about and do that?

Comment: Solved! I moved the COM port opener to the main form instead of a class. And the textbox was also the problem. It didn't start until I clicked ok.

Been stuck for 3 days because of this.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following code.

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>{timer1.Enabled = true;}));
```

Read the MSDN about dispatcher. That will help you understand it.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.begininvoke%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: The question is about Windows Forms, which doesn't have `Dispatcher`. The page you link to is WPF-specific, it doesn't apply here.